# How do i know the reader is at the end value of generator in python

Tags: python, generator

How do i know the reader is at the end value of generator in python??
Example: print 100 primes from 1 to 100

```
def gen(m):
    def snt(n):
        if n<1:
            return False
        else:
            ktra=True
            for i in range(2,n):
                if n%i==0:
                    ktra=False
            return ktra
        for i in range(1,m+1):
            if snt(i)==True:
                yield i
for i in gen(100):
    print(i,end=",")
```

And this is result:

```
1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,
```

*comma in number 97

But I want dot in number 97:

```
1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't know in advance which value is the last, but you know which value is the very first. Print the separator before every value except the first one.

```
first = True
for i in range(10):  # range as an example
    if first:
        first = False
    else:
        print(",", end="")
    print(i, end="")  # see note 1
print(".")

# [1] add flush=True to see the output on terminal as it arrives
```

There is also the `str.join` which is convenient to use.

```
print(",".join(str(i) for i in range(10)), end=".\n")  # with the trailing dot
```

The main difference is that the code above prints a value immediately when it is available, but the `join` needs all values to be collected.